# Highlight new/different items in a list Excel/LibreOffice Calc

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I have a column of data (Version with list of reports), and I have a column of newer data (new version with mostly the same, but some different reports), and I would like to highlight the new/different items in the second column.  I think conditional formatting is what I am looking for.  I'm using LibreOffice Calc at the moment, but I've been looking up Excel help.

This formula `COUNTIF(H3:H30,I3)<1` does what I want, but I can't figure out how to make it scale in LibreOffice Calc.  I think it would scale well in Excel, but I'm not sure.  By scale, I mean copy to other cells.

How can I make this work in LibreOffice Calc?  Can I just copy/paste conditional formatting?  Do I have to switch to Excel to get this to work?

I'm working with a set of ~30 items.  However, the list grows with new versions, and if I have to copy it manually, I might as well manually assign the highlighting too.

Comment: Copy to other cells in column `I`, or to other columns or sheets?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to copy and paste conditional formatting, but it doesn't sound like this will be necessary for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like only one condition is needed, so it should be easy to maintain.

1. Select cells I3 to I50 and go to `Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Condition...`
2. Formula is `AND(I3<>"",COUNTIF(H$3:H$50,I3)<1)`.  Press OK.

[image: conditional formatting]

This is the result:

[image: result]

If the list grows, then modify the condition using `Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage`.